# When can you set Interface Builder objects' properties?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, uikit

When in the view life cycle can you change the values of objects that were put there in IB?

I have a stepper and a UIImageView that I put into the view in IB. I had put some values of them (like the stepper min and the UIImageView's image) in ViewDidLoad but when the view appears, it uses the stepper min and the image that were set in IB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah. I see the problem. I had a UILabel that was displaying the value and I didn't have it set yet to connect to the UIStepper's value until the value changed. My bad. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

You can set the properties where you are trying.

Make sure to call  `[super viewDidLoad]`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];  
    // adjust views here
}
```

It is possible you forgot to connect your IBOutlets in IB:

This will lead to a bug that the compiler does not care about. Essentially your slider code would be equivalent to

```
[nil setMinimumValue:newVal];
```

I can run the following code in a test program and no complaints or crashes happen

```
UIStepper * step = nil;
step.minimumValue = 5;
```

Comment: Regarding the stepper, I have the following in viewDidLoad (after [super viewDidLoad])

`[self.animalCountStepper setMinimumValue:1.0];`

For good measure, I also have the stepper's min value set in IB in the inspector. But it still says 0.

Comment: @WillLarche try NSLog(@"stepper %@", self.animalCountStepper); If that is nil, you forgot to connect the IBOutlet like Rob and I suggested may be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can set those values in `viewDidLoad`.  It would be helpful if you posted your `viewDidLoad` source code.

Since I haven't seen your code, I can only guess at what is wrong.  I suspect that your view controller has a property referencing the stepper and another property referencing the image view, and you are setting the values using those properties, like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.stepper.minimumValue = minValueForStepper();
    self.imageView.image = imageForImageView();
}
```

If your code has that basic structure and it's not working, you probably forgot to hook up those properties in your nib.

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand you question very well, but if you want set your IBOutlets you can do programmatically for example, if you have a:

```
IBOutlet imageView *theImageView;
```

You can set one of UIImageView properties like that:

```
[theImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"theimage.png"]];
```

You can study all the classes that you are interested in the Organizer view of Xcode, here you can view all of its properties, methods, delegate methods and so on.